# how to make rails 3 do something in some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-execution, digital-ocean

I am using the gem:  [scottmotte / digitalocean](https://github.com/scottmotte/digitalocean)
 which seams to be the best. Please inform me on this.

I can create a server using

```
Digitalocean::Droplet.create({:name => droplet_name, :size_id => size_id, :image_id => image_id, :region_id => region_id)
```

But I would like to check after some time if everything is working fine since creating a droplet takes at least 1 minute.

**How can I ask rails to do an API call in some given time, and then, doing something depending on the result? Is there any convention and pattern?**

thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a scheduler for your tasks. Use something like [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for this.